# Which propeller for these motors for rc airplane

Tags: brushless-motors, propellers, fixed-wing, aircraft

I am new to this hobby and I am looking to make a rc airplane myself but I am confused to buy which propeller for this motor?
[image]

[image]
[image: Model plane]
[image: This is the propeller]

Shall i buy CW or CCW propeller

Thanks, Paarth

Answer (score 3):

The size of the propeller depends on the voltage of your battery. Higher voltage batteries will make the motor spin faster, so require smaller props to stay within the power limit of the motor.

2200Kv is a fairly fast motor. A 6" diameter prop will be about the maximum the motor can handle with a 3s (11.1v) battery. That sort of plane would probably work better with a lower speed motor and a larger prop. Maybe 1000-1500Kv with a 8-10" prop.

You can also look at the scale size of the aircraft and work out how large a 'scale' size prop would be, then pick a motor that is suited to that size of prop.

As for prop rotation direction, it doesn't really matter. These motors can run in either direction equally well. For a twin engine plane, you have the option of running a clockwise prop on one side and a counter-clockwise prop on the other side. This eliminates the torque reaction from the motors, which makes it easier to steer in a straight line when taking off.

Comment: Sir now I am going to use 1400kV motors and 10 x 4.5 propelllers will that work?

Comment: That sounds about right. If you find it's too slow, you could try a bit more pitch, like a 10x6

Answer (score 0):

It's all about amps the outrunner is designed to sustain a number of amps by increasing the size of your prop may affect how amps are drawn  into the motor above the max designed amp rating will cause an over load creating excess heat that will destroy the motor always follow the recommendations of the manufacturer of its motor to determining the proper propeller size
a watt meter placed in series with the battery and esc can help verify the amount of amps during testing.

Comment: Welcome to D&MA:SE.  Some punctuation might help us to parse what you're trying to say here.